# How can I get the list of unique words in a column containing strings

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
                                             genres
0         Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller
1                Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller
2          Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Fantasy
3                             Action|Crime|Thriller
4                  Western|Drama|Adventure|Thriller
5         Science Fiction|Action|Thriller|Adventure
6                   Drama|Adventure|Science Fiction
7                 Family|Animation|Adventure|Comedy
8                           Comedy|Animation|Family
9                            Action|Adventure|Crime
10         Science Fiction|Fantasy|Action|Adventure
11                            Drama|Science Fiction
12                    Action|Comedy|Science Fiction
13                 Action|Adventure|Science Fiction
14                      Crime|Drama|Mystery|Western
15                            Crime|Action|Thriller
16                 Science Fiction|Action|Adventure
17                    War|Adventure|Science Fiction
18  Action|Family|Science Fiction|Adventure|Mystery
19                            Action|Drama|Thriller
20                                    Drama|Romance
21                                     Comedy|Drama
22                                           Action
23                    Crime|Comedy|Action|Adventure
24                           Drama|Thriller|History
25                  Action|Science Fiction|Thriller
26                                    Mystery|Drama
27                     Crime|Action|Science Fiction
28                          Adventure|Horror|Comedy
29                                   Drama|Thriller
30        Adventure|Animation|Comedy|Family|Fantasy
```

I am working with a dataframe and one of the columns contains different genres of movies. I wish to get the list of the movie genres present in the genre column. I tried to do this....

```
import numpy as np
df2=np.unique(df['genres'].values)
print(df2)
```

but it just listed the entire genres and not the unique genres.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Use set comprehension for unique values of splitted column by `|`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'genres': ['Action|Adventure|Science Fiction',
                              'Adventure|Science Fiction',
                              'Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Fantasy']})

out = set(y for x in df['genres'].str.split('|') for y in x)
```

Or join values by separator, split long string and convert to set:

```
out = set('|'.join(df['genres']).split('|'))
```

---

```
print (out)
{'Science Fiction', 'Fantasy', 'Action', 'Adventure'}
```

If ordering is important use `dict.fromkeys` trick for remove duplicates in original order:

```
out = list(dict.fromkeys('|'.join(df['genres']).split('|')))
print (out)
['Action', 'Adventure', 'Science Fiction', 'Fantasy']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and pass it to [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set):

```
unique_genres = set('|'.join(df['genres']).split('|'))
```

Or with pandas' [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html), and [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
unique_genres = df['genres'].str.split('|').explode().unique()
```

##### capitalizations and spaces

If the case is not consistent and you have dangling spaces. You should handle them with an extra step:

```
unique_genres = set(s.strip().lower() for s in '|'.join(df['genres']).split('|'))
```

*NB. if you prefer a lower form, replace [`capitalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) by [`lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower).*

Output:

```
{'Comedy', 'Animation', 'Mystery', 'Fantasy', 'Drama', 'War', 'Crime', 'Adventure', 'Science fiction', 'History', 'Romance', 'Thriller', 'Action', 'Western', 'Horror', 'Family'}
```

Or:

```
unique_genres = (df['genres'].str.split('|').explode()
                 .str.strip().str.capitalize().unique()
                )
```

Output:

```
array(['Action', 'Adventure', 'Science fiction', 'Thriller', 'Fantasy',
       'Crime', 'Western', 'Drama', 'Family', 'Animation', 'Comedy',
       'Mystery', 'War', 'Romance', 'History', 'Horror'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a `Series` of unique genres, you can do:

```
>>> (df['genres'].str.split(r'\s*\|\s*')
                 .explode()
                 .drop_duplicates()
                 .reset_index(drop=True))

0              Action
1           Adventure
2     Science Fiction
3            Thriller
4             Fantasy
5               Crime
6             Western
7               Drama
8              Family
9           Animation
10             Comedy
11            Mystery
12                War
13            Romance
14            History
15             Horror
Name: genres, dtype: object
```